# Adding a value to an empty column in pandas for every row without an Index?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I'm reading a CSV through pandas, how do add a fixed value to a column for each row, so I would like to add 'MR' to the CSV file in column TITLE for example, Is it available to use loc without an index?

***Current CSV file***

```
a.csv millions of rows
CODE     NAME TITLE
(Blank)  TIM  (Blank)
(Blank)  John (Blank)
...
```

***Expected Output file***

```
a.csv 
CODE     NAME TITLE
(Blank)  TIM  MR
(Blank)  John MR
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
df.loc[:,'TITLE'] = 'MR'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign values for a whole column by simply giving the column:

```
df['TITLE'] = 'MR'
```